# error in opening Ajax Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, popup

I'm currently building a webapp in MVC C#. I want to open a popup window, where the user can enter lots of information, so he can make a new 'user'. However I have trouble making the window actually pop up. Later on, I'd also like to close the window, though I doubt that'll be much trouble after I got this. Below is my code so far:

```
<button class='btn btn-lg btn-default giveMeSomeSpace leaveMeAlone createUser dialog' onclick='createNewApplication()'>Create a new application</button>

<div class="modal" id="modal-new-app" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-new-app" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...

function createNewApplication() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Create", "User"))',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#modal-body").html(data);
        },
        cache: false
    });

    $('#modal-new-app').modal('show');

}
```

EDIT: corrected a typo, though that wasn't the error. Additionally, the error I get in Console of Chrome dev tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

referring to

```
$('#modal-new-app').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

My and my college have been looking and we got it working.

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-new-app" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-new-app" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close cancel" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new user</h4>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     createNewApplication();
     $('#tableApps').DataTable();

});

function createNewApplication() {
    $.get('@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Create", "UserIS"))', function (data) {
        $('#modal-new-app .modal-body').html(data);           
    });
}
```